# Font size bug on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, fonts, size

I initialized font on every text field. But still Android Google Chrome browser some of text reads by default font size. It means that one text field's font size is bigger than the other one.

http://mamgrow.lt/pagrindinis.html

I used viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
```

Don't really know what to do to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: One of those questions where the poor decision was made to link to a live website for code snippet, which no longer exists. Downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your viewport width to device-width and that should sort it in the latest Chrome.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```